# Codeigniter do_upload function not work on Godaddy server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, file-upload, reference

I'm using Codeigniter (version 3) with the Image upload function in my system. But it is not working when run on the GoDaddy server. It is working fine in localhost and some other live server. Only on godadddy is it not working and earlier it was displaying file permission, so I changed the full control to user and now it shows a 500 error. Check the error image[image: 500 error] I tried so many ways but couldn't get the solution. Please help me.

Codeigniter system installed in a folder of main system
www.mywebsite.com/admin

www.mywebsite.com/admin/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
Options -Indexes
```

www.mywebsite.com/admin/Controller

```
function add_reports()
  {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|xss_clean|trim|max_length[255]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'xss_clean|trim');
    if (empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image', 'required|max_lenght[100]');
    } 
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>','</div>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) //If false redirect to createprofile
    { 
     $data['report'] = $this->dashboard->reports();
     $this->load->view('header',$data);
       $this->load->view('reports');
     $this->load->view('footer');
    } else {
      $url = 'home/reports';
    $image = $this->image_upload_reports($url);
    $pdf = $this->pdf_upload($url);
        $checked = $this->input->post('active');
    if((int) $checked == 1)
    {
      $active = 0;
    } else {
      $active = 1;
    }
    $this->dashboard->add_reports($image,$active,$pdf);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Report added');
    redirect('home/reports');

    }}
    else{
      redirect('');
    }    
  }

    function image_upload_reports($url){
    if(isset($_FILES['image']['size']) != 0){
      $name = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $upload_dir = '../img/';
        //$upload_dir = '/home/***mywebsite.com***/public_html/img/';
    if(!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
         mkdir($upload_dir);
    } 
    $config['upload_path']   = $upload_dir;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['file_name']     = md5($name);
    $config['overwrite']     = true;
    $config['max_size']  = '200480'; // 2MB

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
  $path = $config['file_name'];
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')){ 
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Image not uploaded. Please re-upload');
      redirect($url);
    } 
    else{ 
      // $this->upload_data['file'] =  $this->upload->data();
      return $path.'.'.pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    } 
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Well my first thoughts would be to undo what you did when you "changed the full control to user".

Comment: What kind of server are you using?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw if i undo then it shows "file permission error on line mkdir...". Thatswhy i gave the full permission.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw windows server

Comment: You're getting 500 errors (an internal error) so I'd start by having a good look at your web server logs, they probably have clues about what's happening.

Comment: You need to set write permissions on your images folder.

Comment: @SolarBear I checked the error logs but couldn't fix.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I gave all privilege to "img" folder.
I think its better to change the server to linux from windows.

Comment: I cant vouch for this... It's just something that I found, that might help jog something... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-uyCJ4Gxog. It still sounds like you need to specify those folders to write f you haven't already!

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I changed my package from windows server to linux server and now its working fine :)